# Serverless: enable AWS::LanguageExtensions with an array of resources

Tags: serverless-framework, aws-serverless

To use [Fn::ToJsonString](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ToJsonString.html), I needed to enable `AWS::LanguageExtensions`.

My actual project looks like this:

```yaml
# serverless.yml

resources: ${file(./src/resources.yml)}
```

```yaml
# src/resources.yml

- ${file(./src/resources/resources1.yml)}
- ${file(./src/resources/resources2.yml)}
# ...
```

And my resources files looks like this:

```yaml
# src/resources/resources1.yml

Resources:
    MyResource1:
        Type: AWS::IAM::Role
        Properties:
        # ...
```

To enable `AWS::LanguageExtensions`, I need to have a configuration like so:

```yaml
# serverless.yml

resources: 
    Transform: AWS::LanguageExtensions
    Resources:
        MyResource1:
            Type: AWS::IAM::Role
            Properties:
                # ...
```

I tried modifying `src/resources.yml` like so:

```yaml
# src/resources.yml

Transform: AWS::LanguageExtensions
Resources:
    - ${file(./src/resources/resources1.yml)}
    - ${file(./src/resources/resources2.yml)}
    # ...
```

but I have the following error:

> Transform AWS::LanguageExtensions failed with: Error parsing the template

It seems that it's not possible to have an array of resources under `resources.Resources`

I also tried this:

```yaml
# src/resources.yml

Transform: AWS::LanguageExtensions
Resources:
    ${file(./src/resources/resources1.yml)}
    ${file(./src/resources/resources2.yml)}
    # ...
```

> Cannot resolve variable at "resources.Resources": String value consist of variable which resolve with non-string value

Is it possible to enable `AWS::LanguageExtensions` without modifying the structure of all my resources files ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution was quite simple in fact, as all af the elements seems to be merged:

```yaml
# src/resources.yml

- Transform: AWS::LanguageExtensions
- ${file(./src/resources/resources1.yml)}
- ${file(./src/resources/resources2.yml)}
# ...
```